# How to add DataTable Row's box decoration with spacing in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

[image]

I want to achieve it. I used a data table from Flutter, but it has no properties for Row's. My current code is

```
class CustomDataTable extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomDataTable({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: DataTable(
          dataRowHeight: 80,
          headingRowColor:
              MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.transparent),
          headingTextStyle: TextStyle(color: kDefaultTextColor),
          dataRowColor:
              MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => kSmallCardColor),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: kDefaultBackgroundColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
          ),
          dataTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          columnSpacing: 12,
          columns: const [
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('Column A'),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('Column B'),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('Column C'),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('Column D'),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('Column NUMBERS'),
              numeric: true,
            ),
          ],
          rows: List<DataRow>.generate(
            10,
            (index) => DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(Text('Data $index-1')),
                DataCell(Text('Data $index-2')),
                DataCell(Text('Data $index-3')),
                DataCell(Text('Data $index-4')),
                DataCell(Text('Data $index-5')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to generate a table using either the DataTable or the Table component. However, I'm facing a challenge with these components:

- DataTable applies styling to the entire rows and columns, which is
  unsuitable for my use case.
- Table component doesn't seem to have a margin parameter that would
  allow me to add spacing between the cells.

I'm considering
alternative approaches or solutions to create my desired table.

Comment: You can use ListView widget too instead of Data table. Take expanded with Row widget and add texts into it

Comment: you ca wrap the DataRow item with DecorationBox and use `dividerThickness` but still it will be missing something  &easy to do with ListView ig

Comment: @Vaidarbhi thanks for the comment. I already tried using listview builder but the header is not aligned with the body. Fix sizedbox causes overflow error. I just think about whether is it possible to edit source code or know how flutter renders a row in the data table. Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at [syncfusion_flutter_datagrid](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datagrid)